# Indexers invalid and cron job notification

Tags: magento2, cron, reindex, windows, adminnotification

I installed **Magento** but in admin panel it is giving system message as:

> One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your **Magento cron job**
>   is running

If I am adding categories or products from admin panel It shows no effect on front-end and not even menu and categories are displayed.

Comment: You should reindex manually when you update product data, but you won't be able to run the cron on windows

Comment: I do not recommend use Magento direct on Windows. Please use virtualization to install on supported os.

Comment: @Sanjay As KAndy mentioned, Windows is not officially tested and supported platform for Magento 2. Take a look at [vagrant project](https://github.com/paliarush/vagrant-magento) optimized for Magento 2 development on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You must configure a cron.job in your server to automate a some internal tasks like reindexing, email sending and cleaning between others, there is 3 cron jobs in magento2 you will find all information about that in:

[Configure and run cron](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html)

Magento has a complex db schema to save categories and products data and "render" all these information to a single table per store if you have configured *use flat categories* and/or *use flat catalog* to grant performance on the frontend. This would be the reason why you don't see categories on frontend.

Remember always clean/flush cache too

Answer (score 2):

You can create cron.bat file like this

```
@echo off
cls
:start
echo This is a loop
cd %magento_root%
bin/magento cron:run
sleep 10
goto start
```

to emulate cron.

Answer (score 2):

reindex magento2 using command

Your path like

> var\www\html\magento2\bin

Now You have to enter command

> sudo php magento indexer:reindex

Show your index management all indexes are re-indexed.

**I hope this will help you.**

Answer (score 2):

you have issue of indexing. You can indexing using cli,
Commnad `php magento indexer:reindex`

After successfully run indexing , your issue are gone.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have to run indexing command. if you are using windows than run below command in cmd. you have to run these commands in your magento root directory:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

**NOTE**: If you have just installed magento than you might need to run below commands as well:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out if indexer is stuck you'll have to change it manually in db,

```
UPDATE indexer_state SET status = 'valid';
```

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/126102/45516

Hope this helps,