# Magento 2 How to unlock reindex process

Tags: magento2, stock, reindex

I'm making some tests in Magento reindex process and I locked the **stock index** process.

How can I unlock this process?

```
Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:02
Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:03
Category Products index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Categories index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product EAV index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Stock index is locked by another reindex process. Skipping.
Catalog Rule Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Search index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:06
```

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You can reset the indexer through command line with **`indexer:reset`** command.

This will give the list of indexes name:

```
php bin/magento indexer:info
```

Output:

```
design_config_grid                       Design Config Grid
customer_grid                            Customer Grid
catalog_category_product                 Category Products
catalog_product_category                 Product Categories
catalog_product_price                    Product Price
catalog_product_attribute                Product EAV
catalogsearch_fulltext                   Catalog Search
cataloginventory_stock                   Stock
catalogrule_rule                         Catalog Rule Product
catalogrule_product                      Catalog Product Rule
```

This will give the list of indexes status:

```
php bin/magento indexer:status
```

Output:

```
Design Config Grid:                                Ready
Customer Grid:                                     Ready
Category Products:                                 Ready
Product Categories:                                Ready
Product Price:                                     Ready
Product EAV:                                       Ready
Catalog Search:                                    Ready
Stock:                                             Processing
Catalog Rule Product:                              Ready
Catalog Product Rule:                              Ready
```

If you want to reset all the indexes, you can run the following command:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset
```

If you want to reset particular index (e.g. `cataloginventory_stock`), you can run the following command:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset cataloginventory_stock
```

Comment: Does resetting the index lose any data waiting to be indexed?

Comment: I am also facing same issue in `magento 2.2.4 enterprise edition` i solved using above step but my product is not display on front. what is the problem any idea?

Comment: Great, helped me a lot..

Comment: do you guys have any ideas about this? there is no recent changes made on the store, it just suddenly appeared. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/297085/notice-undefined-index-default-in-vendor-magento-module-catalog-batchsiz

Comment: thanks bro, good explanation

Answer (score 17):

When I faced this kind of situation I had to run the following SQL query directly into the database:

```
UPDATE indexer_state SET status = 'valid';
```

I was not able to to find any option to force reindexing  when an index has failed previously.

Answer (score 9):

On MySQL run:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
update indexer_state set status = 'invalid' where status != 'valid';
```

Then on your terminal run:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

> It normally happens when the memory limit is few, so increase on your
>   **.htaccess** or **NGINX config**.

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible that you run into a state where some tables are locked in MySQL. In this case you can issue `unlock tables;` sql statement to be able to proceed.

I ran into a problem like this:

```
Category Products indexer process unknown error:
SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction, query was: INSERT INTO
```

Where I could not re-index until the table lock was removed.

> Does resetting the index lose any data waiting to be indexed? – ol'bob dole

Indexing is a process of looking at the data set and storing some keys to pair with the proper data. You would lose your current index in the process and it re-creates it. Outside of side effects of index using up resources or your dataset being inaccurate, there should be no risk to re-indexing.

Answer (score 2):

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset
```

Is really bad advice, if you have a store with millions of customers. The reason is it will reset all indexers, including the customer_grid, which will take to a minimum of 40 mins to reindex

Reset selectively please!

Answer (score 1):

Just use the commands:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean full_page block_html
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run these commands:

```shell
php bin/magento indexer:reset;
php bin/magento indexer:reindex;
```

Answer (score 0):

**If index type is locked, when you reindex all the data by running this command:**

> php bin/magento indexer:info

**After running the command above, you will receive the result like the following**:

**In this step, what you need to do is checking the status of all the index types by using this command:**

> php bin/magento indexer:status

**After running the command, you will see the index type Processing status Stock indicates that it is Locked. For more details, see this output
To solve this problem, there is a great solution which is reset the index types which are locked. This example is in the Processing state. Run this command to reset all index types:**

> php bin/magento indexer:reset

**At this step, all you will have to do is check the indexer status one more time. In order to do that run the following command :**

> php bin/magento indexer:status

**You can see in the output, the Stock index type has been unlocked. Besides, the status of it has been changed from Processing to Reindex required.
Now, the Stock index type can be reindexed by using the following command:**

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex

**I hope fix issue.**

Answer (score -7):

I solved this issue with the following steps:

1.- drop table customer_grid_flat

2.- Re-create table:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer_grid_flat` (
  `entity_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entity ID' ,
  `name` text NULL COMMENT 'Name' ,
  `email` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Email' ,
  `group_id` int NULL COMMENT 'Group_id' ,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Created_at' ,
  `website_id` int NULL COMMENT 'Website_id' ,
  `confirmation` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Confirmation' ,
  `created_in` text NULL COMMENT 'Created_in' ,
  `dob` date NULL COMMENT 'Dob' ,
  `gender` int NULL COMMENT 'Gender' ,
  `taxvat` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Taxvat' ,
  `lock_expires` timestamp NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Lock_expires' ,
  `shipping_full` text NULL COMMENT 'Shipping_full' ,
  `billing_full` text NULL COMMENT 'Billing_full' ,
  `billing_firstname` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_firstname' ,
  `billing_lastname` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_lastname' ,
  `billing_telephone` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_telephone' ,
  `billing_postcode` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_postcode' ,
  `billing_country_id` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_country_id' ,
  `billing_region` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_region' ,
  `billing_street` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_street' ,
  `billing_city` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_city' ,
  `billing_fax` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_fax' ,
  `billing_vat_id` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_vat_id' ,
  `billing_company` varchar(255) NULL COMMENT 'Billing_company' ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
  INDEX `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_GROUP_ID` (`group_id`),
  INDEX `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_CREATED_AT` (`created_at`),
  INDEX `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_WEBSITE_ID` (`website_id`),
  INDEX `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_CONFIRMATION` (`confirmation`),
  INDEX `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_DOB` (`dob`),
  INDEX `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_GENDER` (`gender`),
  INDEX `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_BILLING_COUNTRY_ID` (`billing_country_id`),
  FULLTEXT `FTI_8746F705702DD5F6D45B8C7CE7FE9F2F` (`name`, `email`, `created_in`, `taxvat`, `shipping_full`, `billing_full`, `billing_firstname`, `billing_lastname`, `billing_telephone`, `billing_postcode`, `billing_region`, `billing_city`, `billing_fax`, `billing_company`)
) COMMENT='customer_grid_flat' ENGINE=innodb charset=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci

Comment: Don't drop the table :-) Magento creates the tables by scripts! You might miss features that might be on the script.