# Magento 2: Unable to unlock catalogsearch_fulltext reindex

Tags: magento2, reindex

I already tried

[Magento 2 How to unlock reindex process](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126067/magento-2-how-to-unlock-reindex-process)

But below one is not working. It pause for more than 15 minutes. Goes to infinite.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
```