# Indexers are locked automatically: what makes indexers to be locked in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, indexer

What makes indexers to be locked in Magento 2?
What are use cases make the indexers to be locked?

In some cases the indexers are locked automatically, <del>how can we stop this indexers to be locked,</del> what are possible reasons to cause this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2 How to unlock reindex process](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126067/magento-2-how-to-unlock-reindex-process)

Comment: This is not duplicate question, as i mentioned "We fixed the issue by reset indexer" but am asking what are reasons/possibilities to cause this indexers locked.

Answer (score 2):

The default Magento instance locks indexers when full reindex is triggered. This lock prevents partial index updates, which could be overridden by parallel full reindexes. Locked partial updates will be applied immediately after full reindex.

Thus I don't recommend you to disable this functionality.