# Magento 2.2.2 SSH Reindex locked processes help

Tags: reindex, magento2.2.2, ssh

Recently I've been running the SSH command line php bin/magento indexer:reindex

But twice in 3 days it starts to hang after Catalog Product Rule index has been successfully rebuilt..

My server ticket support told me "There are a few reindex processes locked by another reindex process"

What does that mean and why does it happen?

The ones I can see were locked on SSH were:
1. Customer Grid Index
2. Design config grid index

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try below command

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset
php bin/magento indexer:reindexing
```

You can take more information here : [Magento 2 How to unlock reindex process](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126067/magento-2-how-to-unlock-reindex-process)