# Error in reindex process in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, reindex

Due to error in reindex,  Reindex process for 'design_config_grid ' is Skipping

```
Design Config Grid index is locked by another reindex process. Skipping.
Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:10
Category Products index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:05
Product Categories index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:13
Product EAV index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:11
Catalog Search index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:47
Catalog Rule Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:04
Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:06
Search Spell-Correction index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:06
```

So I have taken help from here : [Magento 2 How to unlock reindex process](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126067/magento-2-how-to-unlock-reindex-process)

But, now I am getting this error message ->  "Design Config Grid indexer has been invalidated."

[image]

Please help me to remove this error.

Comment: it has been invalidated so did you try to do again re indexing ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following commands -

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

If did not worked try to run the command in mysql -

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
update indexer_state set status = 'invalid' where status != 'valid';
```

And then run the indexer reset and reindex commands

Comment: 1st option worked for me

Answer (score 1):

For any reason,you design flat is not working

In this case, you have to reset  that design indexing using the command line

`php bin/magento indexer:reset design_config_grid`

then do  reindex this index  individually

`php bin/magento indexer:reindex design_config_grid`